# Как  переоформить функцию в class?

Tags: функции, php, классы

Здравствуйте.

Написал функцию по поиску заданного файла по папкам вверх рекурсией. Но встала задача переоформить все это в класс.

И не получается у меня это сделать, помогите, уважаемые знатоки.

```
$search = "style_stank.css";

function recursion($scan,$search){
    if($dir = opendir($scan)){
        while(false !== ($item = readdir($dir))){
            if($item == $search){
                    $root = "$scan/";// Ищем уровень вложенности
                    $num = substr_count($root, '/');// Считаем кол-во черточек '/'
                    $rt = dirname(__FILE__);// Полный путь до файла
                    $i = 1;

                    while($i < $num){
                        $pos["$i"] = substr(strrchr($rt, "\\"), 0);//Находим последний каталог '/catalog'
                        $rt = strstr($rt,$pos["$i"],true);//Удаляем последний каталог из полного пути до нахождения нужного каталога с искомым файлом
                        $i++;
                    }
                return "$root"."$item";
            }
        }
        closedir($dir);
    }
    $scan.="/..";
    return recursion($scan,$search);
}
recursion($scan=".",$search);
```

Comment: А в чем, собственно, проблема?

Comment: Вот честно, не могу переоформить в класс. В том плане, что отнести в конструктор, как сама рекурсия будет в классе вызываться.